# take multiple input from user on dynamic post name

Tags: php, html, mysql

Please check the codes bellow. I need to take each products quantity value input form user. But the products/id are dynamic and coming form database. how can i receive and identify which products quantity value will be what submitted by user? i mean since product is multiple/dynamic coming form database then so i cant get them by $_POST['id']. whats the solution for this case then?

```
<form method="post">
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Stock Available</th>
      <th>Product Name</th>
      <th>Enter Order Quantity</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

<?php 
$q= mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM products");
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($q)) {
  $id = $row['id'];
  $product_name = $row['product_name'];
  $available_stock = $row['available_stock'];
  echo '
<tr>
<td>'.$available_stock.'</td>
<td>'.$product_name.'</td>
<td><input type="number" min="1" class="form-control" name="qty[]"></td>
<input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="'.$id.'">
<tr>
';
}

?>
  </tbody>
</table><br><br>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submit_next_order2">Confirm This Order</button>

</form>
```

Comment: add the product id name="qty[<?php echo $id; ?>][]"

Comment: ok..good idea then how can i receive from $_POST[]?

Comment: echo $_POST['qty']['your_ids']['your_quantity_get_here'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

if($_POST['submit_next_order2'])
{
 print_R($_POST);die;
}
```

?>
 Please update your html.

```
<?php 
$q= mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM products");
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($q)) {
  $id = $row['id'];
  $product_name = $row['product_name'];
  $available_stock = $row['available_stock'];
  echo '
   <tr>
     <td>'.$available_stock.'</td>
        <td>'.$product_name.'</td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" class="form-control" name="qty['.$id .'][]"></td>
       <input type="hidden" name="id['.$id .'][]" value="'.$id.'">
      <tr>
        ';
     }

   ?>
```